# Selenium cannot find some elements b/c JavaScript page has not finished loading - implicit/explicit wait does not work

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm not sure what's going on here. I am currently using Selenium 2/C# and the browser is IE8.  Our application uses JavaScript when going from one panel to the next, representing a different page but if I am correct everything is still on the same page.  I have tried to use explicit and implicit waits but nothing is working. How can I wait for the actual panel to load before Selenium can begin looking for the elements to perform the various actions?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your html/javascript, this is the only thing which can be advised. Use explicit wait on the javascript condition to get executed. Refer selenium documentation on explicit wait.